# Filter Mongodb Object, from Field of Object present in a field

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, nosql, spring-data-mongodb

I know similar kind of Questions are asked before but this one is a bit different, if you see from dataStructure.

I have following pattern of Data:

```
{  
   "_id":"5d00f6b6c7d0e50d84774f34",
   "_class":"com.mongodb.BasicDBObject",
"memberId":"abc123"
"memberProducts":{  
  "4741333":{  
     "name":"Coleslaw Sandwich",
     "code":"4741333",
     "price":59,
     "quantity":"10",
     "_class":"com.wallet.document.MemberProducts"
  },
  "4772693":{  
     "name":"Add On Chesse",
     "code":"4772693",
     "price":33,
     "quantity":"10",
     "_class":"com.wallet.document.MemberProducts"
  },
  "Ab-123":{  
     "code":"Ab-123",
     "quantity":"1",
     "price":600,
     "name":"Shahi Paneer",
     "category":"Paneer"
  }
},
"daysCount":{  
    "Monday":1
  }
}
```

Now I want to create a query to fetch members which have ordered  which are ordered "Coleslaw Sandwich" more than 5 times. Depending upon `quantity` in `memberProducts` field. Is there any way I can fetch members as per most ordered products? I want to Fetch MemberId from this. 
Thanks

Comment: Will you be more specific about what information you are looking for ?

Comment: I looks like it needs more information such as  : "How are members stored, and what is the schema for members, and where  are the orders stored? How would someone find the different orders made from someones profile"

Comment: Members are stored in diff table but this table has memberid which will be used for mapping. I don't think Schema of Members would make a diff. Orders are stored separately. This table contains detail about items ordered by any member and their count. So I want to perform operation this Collection.